# Image processing: counting individual number pixel in an mask image using Pillow and 3D Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Please help me. I need some opinion on this problem.
**I am trying to count individual number of R,G,B value of an mask image.**

I have an image which is masked filled background with green and it mask a human with red and an object with blue.

***The image size and data type are***
***(1536, 2048, 3)
uint8***

I have tried to access the numpy array of pixels

```
img_path = "sample.png"
i = Image.open(img_path, 'r')
data = asarray(i)
array = np.array(i)
```

But the array only show the background green. Something like below.

```
[[[ 0, 255, 0
    0, 255,0]]]
```

*It does not show red and blue color of an image*

I have tried getpixel()

```
i = Image.open(img_path, 'r')
r, g, b = i.getpixel((0, 0))
print("Red: {}, Green: {}, Blue: {}".format(r, g, b))
```

**It does not count the red and and blue color of mask image.**

How to count the number of R,G,B pixel in mask image?

Where can I find read more about accessing and counting total number of pixels with numpy and pillow?

Please tell me anything related to this.

Comment: Kindly share the image so we can help you without wasting our time guessing what it looks like. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open('hopper.jpg') as im:
    px = im.load()

r, g, b = px[x, y]
print(r, g, b)
```

This code worked for me. **x** and **y** pixel cordinates.
You can get full info from [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html)